# Where did the Dwarves go?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

In Tolkien's stories, we know that the Elves went into the West, but where did the Dwarves go? Did they just die off like the petty Dwarves (Mim and his kin)?

Comment: They've gone... home? To their mountain keeps, their hoards. Maybe find some hairy little dwarf lassies to make some more dwarves?

Comment: "Maybe find some hairy little dwarf lassies to make some more dwarves?" Could actually be fairly difficult and may have been at least partially responsible for their end.  Female dwarves were only a third of the population and a number of them never married (either not being interested or desiring a husband they could not get).

Comment: In the toilet like all other civilised beings?